# How to take data from a string with letters and numbers and turn the number part into a double variable?

Tags: java

I have a label which contains this: Height: 5.36. How would I take the 5.36 part and turn that into its own double variable?

I have tried `numVariable = Double.parseDouble(label.getText())`, but Java obviously doesn't like this as it tries to turn all of it into a double.

Comment: Split the string on a known token, maybe the space, trim the numeric element (probably the second part of the resulting split) and parse that. Maybe start with [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)); for [examples](https://www.baeldung.com/string/split)

Comment: Where does this label come from? If you're building a GUI application (e.g., Swing, JavaFX, etc), then I would reconsider if using this label is the proper way to get the user's input for this "height". Labels are not meant for input.

Answer (score 1):

Split your text to get the number portion.

```
String[] parts = input.split( " " ) ;
```

Grab the number part.

```
String numberPart = parts[ 1 ] ;
```

Parse as a `BigDecimal` if you want accuracy.

```
BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal ( numberPart ) ;
```

Parse as a `double` if you want speed.

```
double number = Double.parseDouble( numberPart ) ;
```